# Format GroovyServer Pages in Intellij Idea

Tags: grails, formatting, intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ Idea CE as an editor for developing a Grails web-app. I created a GSP file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main</title></head>
<body>Welcome, to my online forum, the date today is ${date}
</body>
</html>
```

and tried to format is using ctrl+alt+L but nothing happened.

**My Question**

Can we format .gsp files in IntelliJ Idea and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition does not have any support for Grails development. Full support for Grails development, including formatting for GSP pages, is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.